# Dual Boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows

My laptop has two hard drives, one 320GB HDD and a 30GB SSD. I installed Windows 8 on the HDD and Ubuntu on the SSD. However, after I installed Ubuntu, Windows 8 did not appear on the boot list. I tried boot-repair, but this didn't help.Here is the output of my fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6cd9314a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   625139711   312568832    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 30.0 GB, 30016659456 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3649 cylinders, total 58626288 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6cd93132

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      207126      102539+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          208894    58626047    29208577    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          208896     4112383     1951744   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6         4114432    58626047    27255808   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3965 MB, 3965190144 bytes
49 heads, 48 sectors/track, 3292 cylinders, total 7744512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009c694

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        8192     7744511     3868160    b  W95 FAT32
```

I also tried sudo grub-update, but that also did nothing.

Comment: I'm dual booting with win 8 and it detected fine. You could manually add it to 40_custom for grub, but shouldn't have to. Can you show the output of `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`? Are you on a BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: I'm on bios. The output of that file is too long to post here. Here is a link to it:http://pastebin.com/GqZA43qm

Comment: Yeah grub is not picking it up at all. Does `mount` show anything for /dev/sda?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

http://pastebin.com/T2EXjiK4

Comment: Didn't get here all weekend... Get any where on this? If not, one question - if you open the file manager (Nautilus? I'm on a different distro now so not sure which one it is by default), on the left do you see your windows drive? If you do, clicking on it will mount it, and can you see your windows folders?

Comment: @anujsharma9196 this doesn't look like a usual pre-installed copy to me, fdisk would have complained about GPT tables in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Which drive did you install grub to (HDD or SSD)? Install Grub to SSD and set the SSD as first boot device in your BIOS.

Comment: I installed to the SSD. I tried what you said but there is still no Win8 option.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so open up an administrative Gedit, then navigate to /etc/grub.d/40_custom
I do believe entering

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Should give you an entry in Grub for Windows 8.
After placing that, boot into Ubuntu run sudo update-grub

Comment: Wouldn't it be `set root='(hd0,gpt0)'`?